# Move Group of Layers all in once

Tags: qgis

I have a DXF file which is not geocoded, but it would displayed correctly in QGIS but not at the right place.

There are a hugh amount of layers in subgroups.

Selecting one by one would take hours.

How can i move it to the right point / coordinate?

I do not have AutoCAD.

Is it possible to achive it with QGIS?

Comment: There are free CAD-alternatives. Maybe try one of these?

Comment: If it only needs to be moved, but not warped, use the `translate` tool in batch process mode. If it needs to be warped (which is called "rubber sheeting" for a vector layer), there's a plugin called Vector Bender for that, but I don't know if it has batch processing.

Comment: "Vector Bender" this plugin can only work with *one* layer, not with a complete group.
Ok, let us say i will use freeCad, how can i do it with freeCad?